# graphQL useQuery refetch

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I have multiple queries combined in one request.
Later, when user make some changes I need to ***refetch*** only one of those combined queries with new variables.
I added directives **@include** on those queries that I don't need to fetch again.
The problem is, on ***refetch***, my cache is overwritten with new data from that single query.
How can I persist my cache, ***and only update it*** on ***refetch*** with new data and not overwrite it?

```
const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_DATA, {
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  variables: {
    something,
    includeSummary: true,
  },
});

refetch(
  {
    ...variables,
    includeSummary: false,
  }
);


export const GET_DATA = gql`
  query Something(
    $args: DataInput
    $includeSummary: Boolean!
  ) {
    summary @include(if: $includeSummary) {
      .......
    }

    dynamicData(args: $args) {
      ........
    }
  }
`;
```